# Python: Automatically send Outlook email bypassing the programmatic access warning

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to send out email alerts on my virtual machine using Python. This is my code:

```
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "subject"
newMail.Body = "body"
newMail.To = "me.com"
newMail.display()
newMail.send()
```

I tried to use newMail.send() but my Outlook send the warning which beats the point of automating these alerts. Also, I can't turn off my outlook because 'Windows could not find an antivirus signature' on my machine.

So I tried to use Alt+S after newMail.display() but had trouble because the new e-mail wasn't always in focus.

I then used SetForegroundWindow to ensure that it was in focus but then started getting *pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available')* another SO post suggested that sending keys first and then SettingForegroundWindow fixes the issue and it did work for me.

Now however, every time I close the virtual machine window (not log-off) or it gets locked due to inactivity, even though the rest of the script runs in the background, I get *pywintypes.error: (5, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'Access is denied')* when the email alert is triggered

Is there any workaround to being able to send the email alerts in the background bypassing all these issues?

Thanks,

Sid

Comment: I think you should go back to your first approach and edit your question: post the code you use for send(), and post error message (or snapshot of error/warning dialog). Make it runnable code so we can test it on our system. I'm pretty sure you should be able to send without extended MAPI.

Comment: Hello Scholli, thank you for your reply. I forgot to mention that the warning sent by outlook is - A program is trying to automatically send emails from your computer. Is that okay?

I checked online and the only way to get rid of that, was to allow programmatic access on outlook but my enterprise has a rule where if the antivirus signature is out of date, programmatic access will ask for permission and well, their signature is out of date and they said it cannot be changed from their end.

Comment: @Schollii: Modified the code accordingly. In order to reproduce the outlook warning, you'll need to open outlook > File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Programmatic Access and select Always Warn me about suspicious activity.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no control over the anti-virus, you should look at one of the many options discussed at [Change Outlook's Programmatic Access Options](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/change-programmatic-access-options/). Extended MAPI is just one of many options, which one works if any will depend on many other details of your system.